# Powershell to find file and replace a string in file recursively

Tags: powershell-3.0

I want to search a path recursively for a specific property file. After finding the file(s) I want to search for pattern "@1.0.0" and replace with "@2.0.0"
My script finds the file and the string, but couldn't replace with the newer string.

```
 $RevString=Get-ChildItem -Path $buildFilePath -Filter package.json 
                          -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "@1.0.0"
```

This displays the result as

```
C:\..\package.json:21:
"hl-common-ui-components@1.0.0", C:\..\package.json:21: 
"hl-common-ui-components@1.0.0",
```

I tried the following to replace but it doesn't work

```
 ForEach ($i in $RevString) {
  (Get-Content $i) | 
   Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "@\d.\d.\d","@$major.$minor.$patch" } |  
   Set-content ($i)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$RevString=Get-ChildItem -Path $buildFilePath -Filter package.json -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "@1.0.0"
```

to

```
$RevString=Get-ChildItem -Path $buildFilePath -Filter package.json -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "@1.0.0" -List | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
```

The `-List` parameter to `Select-String` "returns only the first match in each input file". The `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path` says we only want the full path to the file that contains the matching string. `$RevString` will now only contain file names.

`Select-String` returns MatchInfo objects. They have several properties including LineNumber, Line, Filename, and Path. You can see all of them if you pipeline the output to `Select-Object *`, as in:

```
Select-String -Pattern "@1.0.0" -List | Select-Object *
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. IT works and helped me understand the logic better.

Comment: Also I didn't have to use the for loop. The Get-Content searches and replaces all occurrences recursively. SO the code looks like this

$buildFilePath = "c:\temp" 

$RevString=Get-ChildItem -Path $buildFilePath -Filter package.json -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "@\d.\d.\d" -List | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path

(Get-Content $RevString) | 
 Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "@\d.\d.\d","@$major.$minor.$patch" } |  
 Set-content ($RevString)